# Finding the details of user in default login

Tags: php, security, authentication, yii2

I am trying to display the details like username and email of the user who logged in to their account. I am using default login of yii framework and I have `profile` table which authenticates the user. In fact I am trying to pass the username of the user as the parameters. This is the login action which checks for username and password.

```
   public function actionLogin()
    {

           if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/todo/index');  
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login() ) 
        {

            return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/todo/index/<?php echo $model->username;?>');   //this is how i like to pass the username as parameter
        }

        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Default `LoginFrom` Model data is under `getUser` function

So final code will be:

```
public function actionLogin()
    {

           if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/todo/index');  
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login() ) 
        {

            return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/todo/index/' . $model->getUser()->username);   //this is how i like to pass the username as parameter
        }

        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);


    }
```